# WPF prism Custom popup not resizing to content

Tags: c#, wpf, popup, prism

I was following [this](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf/tree/master/27-CustomContent) example on how to create and raise custom popup(so i won't add code because of its basically a clone of that example)

The only thing i changes is i added a `TextBox`

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Count}"  />
```

so i can control the amount of asterisk in the `Content` of the popup

Basically, I have 2 problems:

- The first one is that the title is cut off (this is with 1 asterisk)

[image]

- And the second one is that if i change the content and raise the pop again it does not change the size to fit the content(this is with 50 asterisks)

[image]

but i re-start the program and send 50 asterisks it does fit to fill all those asterisks
[image]

Is there any way to achieve this besides measuring the text width

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
The prism popup-window, once created to contentsize, does not resize when content changes.
I am sure that I have all done everything correct with respect to: BindableBase inheritence, and SetProperty calls.
But once created (and the window gets created once) no resizing takes place.

I have no solution (other than take over the calculation of the window-size).
What I need is a call to force the popup window to (re)resize to new content, somehow.